# what should i do for playing a m4a file in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, m4a

I used pygame and mplayer  library  to play a m4a music file in python languages,but all failed. Is there a library i can use to play m4a file in python?

here is my code:

```
pipes = dict(stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
mplayer = Popen(["mplayer", r"C:\Users\sam\PycharmProjects\untitled\music.m4a"], **pipes)
# to control u can use Popen.communicate
mplayer.communicate(input=b">")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

i used the pycharm ,and the result is :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sam/PycharmProjects/untitled/tt.py", line 23, in 
    mplayer = Popen(["mplayer", r"C:\Users\sam\PycharmProjects\untitled\music.m4a"], **pipes)
  File "C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in **init**
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] 系统找不到指定的文件。

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a good thread that I believe answers the exact same thing that you are having issues with.

[Play m4a in python script with mplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664813/play-m4a-in-python-script-with-mplayer)

Comment: i have tried the Popen way,but the result of running is "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]".I have put the m4a file with the code file in the same path.

Comment: Could you possibly edit your question and share a snippet of your code?

Comment: here is my code:pipes = dict(stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    mplayer = Popen(["mplayer", r"C:\Users\sam\PycharmProjects\untitled\music.m4a"], **pipes)

    # to control u can use Popen.communicate
    mplayer.communicate(input=b">")
    sys.stdout.flush()

Comment: Try moving the file to another location and see if you are getting the same error.

Comment: i changed the m4a file to "c:\",but also the same result.

Comment: I know it seems weird, but this is the only solution I can think of. Try changing the file destination to this: C:\\Users\\sam\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\music.m4a