# Play .m4a in python on android device

Tags: python, file, audio, m4a

I programmed a tkinter script on my android device, which shows you files in a dictionary. You are able to click on a file and then the program gets information like filetype and path to react to it.
In this case I want to play a audio file if it is a m4a file.
I already programmed it to be able to play .mp3, so there is no problem with my pathsystem in my code.

The problem I have is that Im not able to play the file even after hours of researching and trying.

Alternativly converting the file to .mp3 and saving it as "data/temp.mp3" would work aswell, because I would be able to play it with pygame.

I use the newest version of pydroid3.

I dont have anything against libraries I need to install.

I would prefer python, but if it doesnt work in python c++ would work aswell. (Im also using cxxdroid)

I tryed searching in

- StackOverflow
- Reddit
  And more websites I cant remember the name of.

I tryed all the methods I could find. I list (hopefully all of) them here:

- [what should i do for playing a m4a file in python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988911/what-should-i-do-for-playing-a-m4a-file-in-python3) (couldnt install mplayer)
- [Play m4a in python script with mplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664813/play-m4a-in-python-script-with-mplayer) (couldnt install mplayer)
- [how to load m4a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535637/how-to-load-m4a-file-in-python) (failed to install audiotools)

(Yes, there are more links, but most of them are duplicats  or use libraries I cant use)

I also tryed to ask chatGPT for help

All libraries I tryed to use:

- pygame
- playsound
- librosa (failed download)
- mplayer (not for android)
- kivy
- android
- subprocess
- audiotool (failed download)

(It could be that I forgot some)

My goal is to have the knowlege on how to play a m4a file with the path of it.